# Application crash when atlbase.h header is included

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, win-universal-app

My application crash when I include atlbase.h header in my C++ static lib project A, which is added by reference to C++ dll project B, then added by reference to C++ Runtime Component project C. Project C is added by reference to C# universal application D. Let K be class form C project, which indirect way refer to functionality from project A in its constructor. When instance of class K is being created, D application throws exception with that message:

*"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)\r\n   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)\r\n   at WindowsRuntimeComponent2.Class1..ctor()\r\n   at App5.MainPage..ctor()\r\n   at App5.App5_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_MainPage()\r\n   at App5.App5_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()\r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)\r\n   at App5.App.OnLaunched(La"*

Message is understandable but I don't understand why it could not be found, because it works correct when project B is static lib instead of dll  or atlbase.h is not included. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

All projects are universal windows for windows 10 and I test my application on windows phone.

Version of using tools:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.247200.00 Update 1
- Microsoft .NET Fremework Version 4.6.01055

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
You can add _ATL_NO_DEFAULT_LIBS to you project's Pre-Processor which include atlbase.h

Comment: should be a comment.